# Is there a way in Flutter to customize 3D object with Text Overlay or Text Engraving?

Tags: flutter, 3d, threejs-editor

I need to find a way to create a Flutter mobile app with 3D objects that can be configured with text overlay or text engraving.

I found that one: https://sbcode.net/threejs/engraving/ but it seems that is not working properly.

Anyone can help me please? I also take it into consideration to move to another framework.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.